# Corrupted SVG images in PDF build

Tags: ant, pdf-generation, mathjax, dita-ot

I am embedding external svg images in my PDF build process (which uses DITA-OT & Apache Ant) but some of the images are coming out corrupted.  The images are MathMl equations generated by MathJax:

[Good Equation opened in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PGTf.png)

[Corrupted Equation in PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDpU7.png)

Note the distortion on the right paren.

Has anyone ever seen similar?  Is there a fix?

I investigated the internal settings of Ant & RenderX, but neither had an impact.

EDIT:

I've added the clipped image in higher resolution to better display the issues:

Original example
[image: Original example]

Another example (see the K)
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrPYE.png]

EDIT #2

Here's the original SVG file:

[I hope filetransfer.io is OK](https://filetransfer.io/data-package/bKA318Ia#link)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to determine, with the aid of RenderX themselves, that this is due to an internal bug in XEP.  They have a patch that works with the latest version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).